# Firebase database - how do I ensure uniqueness of values before pushing to database if each value has a randomly generated key

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using the Android SDK to write device tokens to my Firebase database. I am associating these tokens to users. I am assuming that each user may have one or more devices. Hence, this is what my current database structure looks like:

```
{
  "users" : {
    "1" : {
      "-LAwu8VKATAxifCOZIPn" : "Device_Token_For_User_1",
      "-LAwyfXcoLcXBX3rOshb" : "Device_Token_For_User_1"
    },
    "8" : {
      "-LAwuR9cel-p0kXv-LCn" : "Device_Token_For_User_8"
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, User 1 (represented by the key "1") contains the same token that was written twice but with different keys (left side). These keys are generated randomly because of the `push()` method. I actually only care about the values themselves, but I want to avoid writing the same token to a particular user more than once.

I push the tokens into my database into the Firebase database this way:

```
String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
Person currentUser;
try {
    currentUser = Reservoir.get("current_user", Person.class);
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();
    myRef.child("users").child(Integer.toString(currentUser.id)).push().setValue(token);
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("ERROR", "Cannot fetch user from reservoir.");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "An unexpected error occurred.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

All is well, except that when a user logs out and logs in back to the same device, the same token will be pushed twice to the database, which is what happened to User 1.

Comment: Why not use the token as the key and give it an arbitrary value like true?

Comment: Another person suggested that I send the tokens directly from the client to my server using a REST API and add the tokens as an attribute of the user, and I have indeed considered that, but that involves adding another column to the `Person` table, and refactoring some fifty or more SQL functions. I think, for now, it's best that I utilize the Firebase db for my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the token as the value you could use it as the key, to ensure it will be unique, and give it an arbitrary value like true.

You would have to change your code like this:

```
myRef.child("users").child(Integer.toString(currentUser.id)).child(token).setValue(true);
```

This will result in the following database:

```
{
  "users" : {
    "1" : {
      "Device_Token_For_User_1" : true,
      "SecondDevice_Token_For_User_1" : true
    },
    "8" : {
      "Device_Token_For_User_8" : true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use the userido, then you can check if the token exists in the database, if it does not exist then you you can add it to the database.

```
String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();
FirebaseUser user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

myRef.orderByChild(user.getUid()).equalTo(token).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(!dataSnapshot.exists()){
               myRef.child("users").child(user.getUid()).setValue(token);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```